# Debian (latest), how to find my machines Host ID/MAC Address/Disk Serial Number

Tags: debian

I am on debian (testing, up to date) and need to find my computers Host ID/MAC Address/Disk Serial Number . The purpose is for license activation (maple). On the internet there is ideas using ifconfig, but that command seems to be replaced by ip. Some simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use ip addr show, there will be a line link/ether...  The 6 sets of numbers and letters immediately after this are the MAC address.

If you have root privs and a terminal window you can get the serial number of your hard drive (assuming here its "/dev/sda") with a command

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda | grep "Serial"
```

Note that this assumes you have smartmontools installed (sudo apt-get install smartmontools)

Note that neither of these things uniquely identify your computer.

Depending on your actual computer, you can often find the systems unique serial number/is with the command

```
sudo dmidecode | less
```

assuming its installed on your system.  (sudo apt install dmidecode).  This will produce an awefull lot of output - and will vary between systems but will generally provide serial numbers or equivalent for your system.   For me, I could get serial numbers - which for my Dell system were the Asset Tag -  data with

```
sudo dmidecode | grep "Serial Number"
```

Comment: Without knowing details, using the MAC address gives you the most flexibility, as this is associated with a network card, and if the system dies in the future you can get another network card with programmable MAC address and assign the old address to the new card - as long as you know what it is.